# Show zero or nothing when displaying gold, silver, and bronze tokens?

Tags: icons, labels, visibility

StackExchange uses a combination of *reputation* and Gold, Silver and Bronze *badges* to show activity.

Is it instantly clear what the following represents?  (picture, reputation, badges)

[image: three gold with only 6 reputation]

Did someone earn 3 gold badges and then spend all their reputation or are they just getting off the ground?

How can this be communicated better?

Is there a reason *not* to show 0 Gold - 0 Silver - 3 Bronze here?  Would that discourage too many people or add clutter for everyone when it's only unclear for some?

Comment: Neither the graphic nor your explanation makes sense to me. That may not be a big deal, if this is just ancillary/meta info. But if it's a core part of your product design, I'd suggest rethinking it a bit. Alas, I don't quite follow how it's supposed to work based on your description so can't really offer specific suggestions.

Comment: Its three bronze badges by the way

Comment: The site has a very good help section which explains this... is this better on meta?

Comment: I'm trying to ask this as generically as possible. Is there a reason *not* to show 0 Gold - 0 Silver - 3 Bronze here?  Would that discourage too many people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a reason *not* to show 0 Gold - 0 Silver - 3 Bronze?**

From my own experience, I only have bronze badges. My avatar looks visibly barer than someone who has bronze, silver and gold badges. Simply put, I endeavour to invest more time and effort into the site in order to earn these things to make myself appear more trustworthy and respected on the site.

You could also argue that showing 0 may have the same motivational effect, however, having a visibly more empty display of achievements is more powerful.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes less is more. Putting in 0 adds unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Someone unfamiliar with the badge system could see you as having 8 gold medals.  That problem goes away by being explicit.

Comment: Someone unfamiliar with the badge system would hopefully read up about it. And even if they did I doubt it would be something to be frustrated about and leave the site. I do not really see how it is a problem..